# Texto con horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Buenas tardes comunidad,

Estoy tratando de hacer el efecto que tiene el texto de esta pagina https://thec8.com/about, adjunto imagen del apartado del texto que me interesa animar al scrollear hacia abajo o arriba.

Saben con que librería hace este efecto? como pueden ver, al scrollear hacia abajo, el texto se mueve de izquierda a derecha y viceversa, pero a su vez la pagina scrollea y conforme bajas el texto se mueve.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Es un efecto que puedes lograr con puro css sin necesidad de frameworks con la propiedad transfom de css https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transform y con con translateX().

No hay un código especifico que te pueda compartir ya que dependerá de que es lo que quieras lograr. Experimenta con esas propiedades y si tienes problemas generas otro post.